# Suggestions on a good Javascript Multi Select Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have an application I'm developing that has some multi and single select lists that can contain a lot of items. In the interest of time I don't really want to write my own widget right now, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding what I want.

Here are the requirements: 
1) It must be a select list under the covers; I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 so so make form submission and model binding easier I really need it to be an actual select list

2) It must be searchable

3) I really want selection and deselection to be a single click (rather than ctrl+click to select multiple items)

4) A select all and deselect all would be a plus

5) Bonus points if it uses jquery UI as a base, since I'm already using those libraries

6) it must NOT use theme roller for styling...it has to be easy to independently style

7) No side by side type controls where the selected items go on the right. disliked by the designer and myself.

The closest I have found is http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/, but number 6 ruins it for our use. Why don't we want to use theme roller you ask? Well I am no CSS guru and our designer hates it, so its out of my hands.

I have found quite a few things that have one or two criteria, but non that have them all.

Can someone save me from wasting days (at minimum) rolling my own widget?

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a project where I needed one. I spent a long time trying to use this one:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

HOWEVER I really found it limiting and it caused weird things to happen to positioning of form elements in position:fixed divs as well as being tricker to show/hide and animate so I changed to this:

https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

which was way better in my opinion also it was simpler to implement and didn't mess with anything else on the page so much.

Best
Alex

Comment: Unfortunately that is the same as http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ :)

Comment: wierd, must have missed you mentioning it sorry.. that said, it can be styled pretty nice, I did the basic stuff in theme roller simply to be quick and then I customised the css to what I wanted, have a look at the dropdowns here: http://tropicusholidays.com/special-offers